# String comparisons while getting passwords

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I'm going to ask a very basic question but since I'm getting this problem and I'm not getting why this is happening. Usually when we compare two strings like s1==s2 , it compares with length, characters, cases etc but while working in linq with the following query it is not matching the cases of the string. My DB has Password123 but when I enter password123, then also it return me a record which is actually wrong.
My query is:
 `var row = DB.tbllogin.Where(m => m.Id == LoginId && m.Password ==` `pwd.Trim()).FirstOrDefault();`

It is not matching the cases.The field in DB is of nvarchar type and pwd is of string type
and I am using Entity Framework ORM.

Comment: I take it your DB is using a Case Insensitive collation? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4204515/sql-server-case-insensitive-collation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql

Maybe this will help! :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104520/linq-case-sensitive

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the comparison is being performed in SQL - I suspect if you execute the same query in SQL Studio, you'll get the same result.

One fix would be to change the database collation to be case-sensitive; it's not clear whether you *can* do this directly in LINQ itself. (It's one of those cases where the details are leaking through the abstraction.)

However, a better solution for this *specific* case would be to *not store your passwords in plaintext to start with*. It's horribly insecure. You should be storing a hash using something like `bcrypt`. See [Jeff Atwood's blog post on the topic](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/speed-hashing.html) for more details.

Comment: `StringComparison` won´t work. That is also transformed to "=" which ist case-insensitive.

Comment: @Jehof: Interesting. Will delete that bit, thanks. (I'm keeping the answer due to the "don't store passwords like this" even though it's mostly otherwise a dup.)

Comment: this won´t work at least for Entity Framework, which i have tested in LinqPad. I am not sure if the questionar uses EF but i guess he uses it.